# Can't map Angular5 HttpClient responses to my typescript classes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-httpclient

I have a problem mapping my Angular 5 HttpClient responses to concrete TypeScript classes.

I have a following Angular 5 class:

```
export class MaintainableUser {

  constructor(public id: string, public name: string, public privileges: string[]) {
  }

  public hasPrivilege(privilege: string): boolean {
    return this.privileges.indexOf(privilege) != -1;
  }

  public togglePrivilege(privilege: string) {
    if (this.hasPrivilege(privilege)) {
      this.privileges.splice(this.privileges.indexOf(privilege), 1);
    } else {
      this.privileges.push(privilege);
    }
    console.log(this.privileges);
  }
}
```

I have a following Angular5 service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {MaintainableUser} from './maintain-users/maintainable-user';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {ApiErrorHandler} from '../api-error-handler';

@Injectable()
export class AdminService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private errors: ApiErrorHandler) {
  }

  getAllUsers(): Observable<MaintainableUser[]> {
    return this.http.get<MaintainableUser[]>('api/admin/users').pipe(catchError(this.errors.handle));
  }

}
```

That's nice and clean and now I can use my service like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MaintainableUser} from './maintainable-user';
import {AdminService} from '../admin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-maintain-users',
  templateUrl: './maintain-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maintain-users.component.scss']
})
export class MaintainUsersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private adminService: AdminService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadMaintainableUsers();
  }

  private reloadMaintainableUsers() {
    this.adminService.getAllMaintainableUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data[0] instanceof MaintainableUser);
        data[0].hasPrivilege('ADMIN');
      },
      err => {
        console.log('Service error: ' + err);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Problem is that the data I receive is not actually a list of MaintainableUser. The response block from my MaintainableUsersComponent has the following output:

> {"id": "john", "name": "John Doe", "privileges": ["ADMIN"]}
>
> false
>
> ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.hasPrivilege is not a function

Why is that? Why is my data[0] not instanceof MaintainableUser? I'm very new with Angular but I understand from different tutorials that since version 4 I should be able to auto map exactly like that to my classes/interfaces. Or is it just a fake thing so you could be safe that your object is strongly typed but you can not be sure it is instance of the actual object itself? It would be really nice if I could have some helper methods in my response classes so I could use them in view's for example, but currently I have not found a clean way to do it.

Comment: I don't consider any of the solutions on StackOverflow to be a comprehensive solution to the problem.

So, I created an npm package angular-http-deserializer for this:
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-deserializer#usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rather problem with understanding how classes/objects work. What is returned from API is just a plain object (parsed JSON) which doesn't have any methods of `MaintainableUser` because it is not instance of your class. It only has same properties as your class.

You need to manually pass values from object into constructor and create instance of your class. Angular doesn't do it automatically. I often do something like this:

```
export class MaintainableUser {

  public static createInstance({ id, name, privileges }): MaintainableUser {
    return new MaintainableUser(id, name, privileges);
  }

  constructor(public id: string, public name: string, public privileges: string[]) {}

  public hasPrivilege(privilege: string): boolean {
    return this.privileges.indexOf(privilege) != -1;
  }

  public togglePrivilege(privilege: string) {
    if (this.hasPrivilege(privilege)) {
      this.privileges.splice(this.privileges.indexOf(privilege), 1);
    } else {
      this.privileges.push(privilege);
    }
    console.log(this.privileges);
  }
}
```

And then:

```
getAllUsers(): Observable<MaintainableUser[]> {
  return this.http.get<MaintainableUser[]>.('api/admin/users').pipe(
    map(MaintainableUser.createInstance)
    catchError(this.errors.handle)
 );
}
```

Comment: OK. I was afraid of that, but was hoping it does something more fancy. I come from a Java world and there for example if I serialize JSON with GSON, it uses setters to set the values but I still have my concrete class when it's finished. Thanks. Your alternative seams feasible enough in the lack of cleaner options.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MaintainableUser` *type* is being mapped just fine, so the HttpResponse is correctly mapping that generic type and the Typescript compiler isn't complaining, but your response is not an *instance* of `MaintainableUser`. It's still just an object that was parsed from JSON.

Your `MaintainableUser` class has a method property, which is equivalent to adding that method to `MaintainableUser.prototype`. In fact, that's exactly what the Typescript compiler does, when targeted to ES5.

Remember that Typescript types have *no* effect on the transpiled Javascript. Passing that `MaintainableUser[]` type to the `HttpClient` simply adds strong typing to the response. Essentially, you're just telling your IDE and the compiler that the Response is a `MaintainableUser[]`, but it's not actually an *instance* of `MaintainableUser`. You need to use the `new` keyword to pass on that prototype.

I'd refactor `MaintainableUser` to accept that Response as a constructor parameter and map the response to a new instance of `MaintainableUser`, or move the `hasPrivelage` method to a service.

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` checks the prototype chain, so unless your `getAllMaintainableUsers()` is creating new `MaintainableUser` objects, it will return false. My guess (from your `getAllUsers()` call above) is that you are directly returning an object from a service. Even though you are annotating the type as `MaintainableUser[]`, since it is not created with the prototype of `MaintainableUser`, instanceof will not return true for `data[0] instanceof MaintainableUser`.